# Trial booting with Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I would like to try Ubuntu without replacing Windows 7. I have burned an image of Ubuntu 16.04.1 L using Roxio 3.7.0 (2007) which copies to destination PLDS DVDRW DL (`D:`). Clicking <kbd>F12</kbd> I get to the boot menu.

Do I then select:

- Legacy Boot/PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8APSH

or

- WEFI BOOT/WEFI: PLDS DVD+/-RW DS-8A8SH?

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of trying Ubuntu without installing, choose the WEFI option (did you mean UEFI?). Both of the options should work, but you might as well boot in EFI mode if you can.

If you decide to install Ubuntu, then it matters which one you choose. You need to determine whether or not Windows 7 is EFI or Legacy, and choose the corresponding boot option.